# Не удаляется событие с window

Tags: javascript, html, css, ооп, listener

Не удаляется обработчик, хотя функция передаётся одинаковая

```js
class CheckInterection {
    constructor(element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    get windowPosition() {
        return {
            top: window.scrollY,
            left: window.scrollX,
            bottom: window.scrollY + document.body.clientHeight,
            right: window.scrollX + document.body.clientWidth,
        };
    }

    get targetPosition() {
        return {
            top: window.scrollY + this.element.getBoundingClientRect().top,
            left: window.scrollX + this.element.getBoundingClientRect().left,
            bottom:
                window.scrollY + this.element.getBoundingClientRect().bottom,
            right: window.scrollX + this.element.getBoundingClientRect().right,
        };
    }

    checkVisible() {
        this._targetPosition = this.windowPosition;
        this._windowPosition = this.targetPosition;
        if (
            this._targetPosition.bottom > this._windowPosition.top &&
            this._targetPosition.top < this._windowPosition.bottom &&
            this._targetPosition.right > this._windowPosition.left &&
            this._targetPosition.left < this._windowPosition.right
        ) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

class AnimationText extends CheckInterection {
    constructor(element) {
        super(element);

        this.endAnimate = false;
        this.#addStyleDisableAnimation();
    }

    #addStyleDisableAnimation() {
        this.element.style.transform = "translate(-50px, 0px)";
        this.element.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }

    #removeStyleDisableAnimation() {
        this.element.style.transform = "translate(0px, 0px)";
        this.element.style.visibility = "visible";
    }

    animation() {
        console.log(this.endAnimate);
        this.visibility = this.checkVisible();

        if (this.visibility) {
            this.#removeStyleDisableAnimation();
            this.endAnimate = true;
        }
    }
}
document.querySelectorAll(".title").forEach((element) => {
    const animate = new AnimationText(element);
    const funcrionListener = animate.animation.bind(animate)
    window.addEventListener("scroll", funcrionListener);
    if (animate.endAnimate) {
        window.removeEventListener("scroll", funcrionListener);
    }
});
```